# ShortestPath in hierarchical graph between nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to extract shortest path from green left bottom circle to top blue.
I try

`MATCH (n:AclEntry) ,(n)-[*]->(sid) 
   with sid,n
   MATCH (n)-[*]->(c)
   where c.objectId='someClass5' and sid.guid='admin'
   RETURN sid, n LIMIT 25`

also try shortesPath, but with empty result.
[image]

Comment: seems, i found, one of possible solusions.

`MATCH (c:AclClass), (s:AclSid),
p=shortestPath((c)-[*]-(s))
where c.objectId='someClass5' and s.guid='root'
RETURN nodes(p) LIMIT 25`

Comment: You've provided a screenshot of your graph, which is great, but you've only given sparse context. We don't know which labels are used where and why, and we don't have a good grasp of your use cases, and whether we can rely on an exact path as shown to be present, or if there are variable relationships involved. Please provide more detail if you want others to be able to offer solutions.